# Git command within ignored folders - can it truly ignore that it is within a git repo?

Tags: git, gitignore

I'm having a git repo setup in my main users directory in order to sync configuration among my computers like so:

```
/Users/myusername/.versionedConfigFile
/Users/myusername/myOtherFolders <-- to be igored
/Users/myusername/projects/somerepo/.git <-- to be igored
```

Besides these configuration file I want everything else to be ignored in my git repo, which is why my .gitignore looks like this:

```
   *
   !.gitignore
   !.versionedConfigFile
```

While .gitignore allows me to exclude all my other files from *tracking*, I can still see that I'm in a git repository when I cd into "myOtherFolders" for example and running git commands like "git status". I would prefer to see "not a git repository" here to not get confused when working with other git repos in my directory tree (which still works of course).

Is there a way to "truly" exclude the folders from the .git repository?

Comment: The main problem is that you use git for synchronizing your computers. Git is not the right tool for this. So I think this is not the right question, you rather want to know which tools you can use for synchronizing (see https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option would be to:

- have your Git repository in a separate location, with in it your `.versionedConfigFile`
- have a symlink in `/Users/myusername/.versionedConfigFile` to that separate repository.

That way, you don't have to ignore everything, and you can have other repositories in `/Users/myusername/`.